# Number of declared elements in an array c

Tags: c, arrays, size, element

I have created a static array in c

`int array[15];`

For example, I "filled in" the first 5 elements of my array.

This means that I still have 10 free elements, right?

What should I do to know that I have already "used" five elements of my array?
How would I know the number of elements that I have used?

Comment: It's for you to decide if the values you have in the array are valid or they are just junk. There is always something in your array because every address in memory contains something. If you have an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), the initial contents of the array are what happens to be at that address in memory where your array is stored. If you have a [static variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable), then the contents of the array are initially zero.

Comment: If you were expecting the array to automatically keep track of this for you somehow, if you wanted a way to "ask" the array how many elements you've filled in, I'm afraid you're out of luck.  You have to keep track of this yourself somehow.  (In other words, C arrays are *not* C++ std::vectors.)

Answer (score 3):

> What should I do to know that I have already "used" five elements of my array? How would I know the number of elements that I have used?

There are couple of options.

1. Use a sentinel value that indicates the elements that have been filled up.
   Let's say you use `99999` for the sentinel value. If the `n`-th element of the array has the value `99999`, you know that you have filled up `n-1` elements.
2. Use another variable to keep track of that.

   ```
   size_t numFilledElements = 0;

   for ( ... )
   {
      // Fill up an element

      // Increment the counter.
      ++numFilledElements;
   }
   ```

My personal preference would be to use the second approach. Then, you won't have to worry about a sentinel value.

Comment: With regards to approach 2 (which is indeed preferred), it is common to write `array[numFilledElements++] = whatever`.  A great way to understand the difference between prefix and postfix `++` is to observe why postfix `++` is what you want here, while prefix would not do the right thing.  (It turns out that you might want prefix if you had a 1-based array, though.)

Comment: @SteveSummit, it's hard for me to assess how common it is to combine the setting of the value of the element and incrementing the counter to one statement but I personally separate them into two statements.

Comment: Recommend using `size_t` rather than `int` for `numFilledElements`.

Comment: @chux, I second that.